# Asymmetry effect vs leverage effect

Tags: self-study, terminology, garch

Regarding GARCH models, many authors use the terms *asymmetric effects* and *leverage effects* interchangeably and they left me with a doubt on whether these two terms are synonymous.

I get that, for example, in asymmetric GARCH models, good news and bad news have different effects on the variance; however, I'm guessing this means that asymmetric effects are present. If so, then what is the distinction with leverage effects?